# How to acces vuex store inside a .js file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

```html
import store from '../store';
import messages from './messages';
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n';

Vue.use(VueI18n);

console.log(store); // undefined

const i18n = new VueI18n({
  locale: 'en', // set locale
  messages: messages, // set locale messages
});

export default i18n;
```

I want to be able to change the locale upon state change but it always yeilds undefined.

Comment: Is `store.js` in the parent directory?

Comment: Src/store/index

Comment: Also i am using the modules attr if that makes any difference, also i am sure that path is correct

Comment: You are indicating in the code, using `../store` that `store` is in the parent directory from whatever file you are showing. If `store` is *not* in the parent directory, then it is going to be undefined.

Comment: Parent directory is the src

Comment: Can you share your `store/index.js` file here?